# Extracting text from html and writing out to s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am day 1 fresh using javascript and html. I am simply trying to extract text once a button is clicked and write out that text to an s3 bucket. I have an html file that contains the html and java script function that will extract the text. Now I just need to write that data to s3.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <center>
        <label for="freeform">Please decribe what you would like photo-ai to create:</label>
        <br>

        <textarea id="freeform" name="freeform" rows="4" cols="50">
            Enter text here...
        </textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Submit my Application!" onclick="formdata()" />
        </center>
        
        
    </body>
</html>


<script>

    function formdata() 
    {
        var free_text= document.getElementById("freeform").value;


    }

</script>
```

I see stuff in Node.js but I am not sure the way I am doing here is possible. Basically I am lost and I am asking for guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On day one you should definitely learn something else than using AWS S3 SDK to upload objects to S3 bucket, but here are the official SDK with some examples how to make it work:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-examples.html

Comment: Thank you what do you suggest to learn?

Comment: Take a full plain JS scourse to learn the language thoroughly. You will need it when learninf advanced topics. You will find a lot of free courses by googling. One candidate would be: https://www.w3schools.com/js/ Taking HTML and CSS courses would help too. After that you are ready to learn using Javascript frameworks which help a lot to create real applications. There are a lot of alternatives React, Angular and Vue being the most popular. Taking a general AWS course like AWS Cloud practitioner would be good idea and and after that topics like integrating AWS services to your apps.

Comment: Understanding basic concepts of AWS properly is mandatory because you have to understand how to secure your workloads and access to your resources etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I actually work at Amazon and I am certified with AWS cloud practitioner. Ill definitely take the course for js you suggested tho.